# What is the command code for Wolfram Warptangent, Point Release 0.10.2.1?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I am brand new to Linux and just got the older version up and running! Now I have to change but am unsure as to what command code to use.  I am sure that is similar to what I previously used;~/bin $ wget https://downloads.getmonero.org/linux64.

But... I don't think this will get me the update?

Answer (score 6):

In your browser, go to getmonero.org and look for the announcement of the new release. Click on that announcement. Look for the "Linux, 64-bit" download link. Right-click on that link and copy the URL, which is the compressed .bz2 file. Then, in a terminal, you can paste the link by right-clicking in the terminal and selecting "Paste." Type *wget* first and then paste:

```
wget https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/monero-linux-x64-v0.10.2.1.tar.bz2
```

This will download the compressed files which are already in their own directory. Before extracting it, it's a good idea to verify the sha256 of the .bz2 file to ensure it wasn't tampered with. Do this with:

```
sha256sum monero-linux-x64-v0.10.2.1.tar.bz2
```

Check the output with the sha256 listed on the announcement page. Now, you can extract the directory which contains the point release binaries with:

```
tar -xf monero-linux-x64-v0.10.2.1.tar.bz2
```

cd into the new directory and start the daemon with:

```
./monerod
```

This will download and sync the blockchain, which is stored in /home/yourusername/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb

After the blockchain has downloaded, copy your existing wallet to the new directory, or you can create a new wallet. Open another terminal in the new directory, and if using an older wallet:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file [walletFileName]
```

Don't include the brackets when you enter your wallet file name. Or, if you want to create a new wallet:

```
./monero-wallet-cli
```

From there, it will walk you through the creation of your wallet, which takes at most 1-2 minutes. Enjoy!